# Active Directory Claims based Authentication error in SharePoint

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-2010, windows-registry, permissions

I am trying to log into a new SharePoint application, which has it's authentication method set to Claims based authentication (CBA). The user I am logging in with is Site collection admin. When trying to log in I get the access denied page. When looking in the event log on the WFE the site is running on, I see the following error:

> An exception occurred in Active
>   Directory claim provider when calling
>   SPClaimProvider.FillResolveClaim():
>   Requested registry access is not
>   allowed.
>
> Event ID: 8307
>
> **User: NT AUTHORITY\IUSR**

I get why IUSR would not have registry access, but why would SharePoint run a request under that account, the webapp is running under a domain service account? Pretty much everything is running as it should except this web app. The Claims based authentication is needed because of search requirements (one-way domain trusts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up rebuilding the farm, after a clean install verything worked. One-way domain trusts need a lot of pre work is all i can say...

Comment: Truth! I feel your pain. :-/